# How Upload test results to alm by Jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, hp-alm

I am using HP ALM v 5.2 and uploaded my test results by making free style project from the gui now I want to add this step to pipeline, I searched on the internet and found this guide but gives me this error `no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named TestResultToALMUploade` with to many exceptions 
this is sample of code

```
junit testResults: '**/target/*-reports/TEST-*.xml', allowEmptyResults: true
    step ([$class: 'TestResultToALMUploader',
        almServerName: 'HP ALM Server', //almServerName
        credentialsId: 'ALM-CREDENTIALS',
        almDomain: 'ALMDomain', // almDomain
        almProject: 'AlmProject', //almProject,
        testingFramework: 'JUnit', //testingFramework
        testingTool:  '', //testingTool
        almTestFolder: 'TestHPALM', //almTestFolder
        almTestSetFolder:  'TestHPALM', //almTestSetFolder
        almTimeout:  '-1', //almTimeout
        testingResultFile:  "**/junitResult.xml", //testingResultFile
        jenkinsServerUrl:  ''  //jenkinsServerUrl                    
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if you already found the answer, but I managed to do it with adding this fragment to "publishers" section:

```
job {
    parameters { ... }
    steps { ... }
    ... // some other job configuration here ...
    publishers {
        archiveJunit("junitReport.xml")
        testResultToALMUploader {
            almServerName('HP ALM Server')
            credentialsId('ALM-CREDENTIALS')
            almDomain('ALMDomain')
            almProject('AlmProject')
            testingFramework('JUnit')
            testingTool('')
            almTestFolder('TestHPALM')
            almTestSetFolder('TestHPALM')
            almTimeout("")
            testingResultFile("**/junitResult.xml")
            jenkinsServerUrl('')
        }
   }
}
```